Where Does the 'fi' in 'Authentication' Come From in East Slavic Languages?
I've noticed that some languages, seemingly restricted to East Slavics, add an extraneous 'fi' to the word 'Authentication'. E.g. Bulgarian and Serbian spell it 'Автентикация' and 'Autentikacija', as one would expect. But in Ukrainian and some others it's often rendered "автентифікація". Where is the 'fi' coming from, and is there a name for the phenomenon of such additions (IIRC it also happens with some other words)?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7844/is-authentification-a-real-word

Serbian and Serbo-Croatian in general is not consistent on this, by the way.

These terms are often very new and used some native words instead before. See this article in Czech from 2004 (machine translation should help) https://www.interval.cz/clanky/hrichy-pro-sileneho-korektora-autentizace-autentikace-nebo-autentifikace/ None of the forms was clearly established by that time in Czech (despite autentifikace being listed in the answer above, it was not super common according to the corpus).

That exact variation started in the West and spread East.
Latinate internationalisms like this generally went from French into German, and then from into those languages of the East, under some parallel reinforcing influence directly from French.
In German and Serbo-Croatian you can find it both ways (or with a native ending like Authentifizierung), not sure about Ukrainian.
